# What is 'context.Wait' use for in BotFramework

Tags: c#, botframework

I use the BotFramework to realize a bot, and I use the interface IDialog.
In the Dialog, call EchoDialog, the main code is below:

```
public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var activity = await result;
        await context.PostAsync($"{count++},You said: " + activity.Text);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
```

and the MessagesController.cs main code:

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
    {
        if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
        {
            await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new EchoDialog());
        }
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

The code run well. But if I comment the code(in the EchoDialog.cs,in function MessageReceivedAsync):

```
context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
```

The code run result is the same as the uncommented result, that is it can still echo what use input.

So what is `context.Wait` indeed use for?

Answer (score 3):

`context.Wait(...)` defines which method the dialog should use when the next message of the user is received, i.e. the method that gets called by the controller when it receives a new message.

EDIT: By leaving the line out in the `MessageReceivedAsync` method the framework will keep reusing the same method to respond to messages.

Comment: em.. in my case, it is not necessary to use the code: context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync); ?

Comment: Do you comment both lines?

Comment: just comment the line in function MessageReceivedAsync

Comment: I just tested it out. Seems to me like this is a new behavior. Previously you always had to tell the bot which method to use next. Looks like it will now remember the last used method and reuse that one.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please mark the answer as correct so other users know it's correct.

Comment: can you point out where the conclusion(the framework will keep reusing the same method to respond to messages.) comes from

Comment: It's hard to pinpoint that to one point. The best place you can see it is [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DialogTask.cs) in the methode `WaitNext`, all the `IThunk` classes and further down `IDialogStack.Wait<R>(..)`